# want to keep blockquote element in a seperate line

Tags: html, css

We are trying to keep out blockquote element in a different line. So we have tried applying clear:both and display:block css properties both but nothing seems to be changing we are targeting ie7 and firefox 3 browsers please help.

```
<p>  This is text </p>
<p>  This is text </p>
<blockquote  style='clear:both;display:block;float:left'     >
<p>  This is text </p>
</blockquote>
<p>  This is text </p>
<p>  This is text </p>
```

Comment: Please post what code you have already (HTML and CSS), and ideally (but optionally) a demonstration of what you have at the moment.

Comment: Without applying any styles, every paragraph should already be in its own line. What's your problem?

Comment: blockquote is on it's own line. What are you looking to do.

Comment: I think there is some style applied to paragraph so that blockquote and paragraphs are coming on same line. Let me figure it out and will ask question after a little clarification. Thanks BoltClock

Comment: I have edited my question My blockquote is having float left. And for some reason i need to put it there i am not good at CSS so i cant judge a alternate.

Comment: What do you need your page to look like? We can't visualize what you want.

Comment: If you remove float:left, what happens that you don't want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to set the clear attribute on the parent element of the floated element. Clearing and floating within the same element isn't going to do what you intend to do. Right now, you are clearing anything that is floated *within* the blockquote. Secondly, from what you have given us and from what you say you want to do, there is no point in floating the blockquote because what you want happens without floating it. If you are messing with alignment, just align the blockquote to the left of its container.